# Python web scraping userlist

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape a userlist from a website, but it has multiple pages, I'm able to scrape the first but stuck when it comes to scraping each page.

Code -

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

source = requests.get('example.com/users.php?page=1').text

soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')

for profile in soup.select("li h3 a"):

    print(profile.text)
```

notice in url

```
page=1
```

well next page, is

```
page=2
```

and so on, so my question is how would I get python to scrape first, then the second and so on.. It would be more effective if I could assign it a page limit, like

```
 1-1000
```

so it doesn't attempt to exceed the pages and hit a blank.

Comment: Can you scrape `example.com/users.php?page=2` now? If the answer is yes, you may run a for loop to scrape pages with a range.

Comment: yes I can :), but page turning seems, strange it's using + 20 each time, so page 1 = 0, page 2 = 20, page 3 = 40, page 4 = 60 and so on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
page_size = 0
for page_no in range(1,1000):

    source = requests.get('example.com/users.php?page={}'.format(page_size)).text
    page_size += 20
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'lxml')
    for profile in soup.select("li h3 a"):
        print(profile.text)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
no_of_user_to_scrape = 20
for page_no in range(1, no_of_user_to_scrape):  # iterate over pages
    response = requests.get("http://example.com/users.php", params={"page": page_no}) # will construct url like http://example.com/users.php?page=page_no where page_no is iteration 1,2,3....
    # rest of the code goes here....
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')

    for profile in soup.select("li h3 a"):
        print(profile.text)
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I have accepted Vaseem's answer as that is the one I followed initially ( first I saw ), but for anyone who may read over this in due time following the same question, this answer works just as effectively as the first.

Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0):

If your scraper also works on `example.com/users.php?page=2`, you can simply iterate over those pages with an additional for loop. You will somehow need to see if a page has any entries in order to handle the condition for the loop when to finish.